# Can't display all upsell products in magento, 1 product is missing

Tags: magento-1.9, products, up-sells, upselling

I don't understand why upsell doesn't show 1 product in the frontend. All upsell products are showing up except for 1. I've reindexed all data, but still no changes. All upsell products are in stock, they all have quantity and they are all enabled, but still 1 product doesn't show up in the frontend. I've tried to check only 1 product, which is the product that is missing but didn't show up, any help, please. Thanks. By the way, it is not modified in the catalog.XML so the product limit is not the issue.

here is the backend http://ecommerceoutsourcing.co/projects/UMD/magento/skin/frontend/default/theme542/images/upsell_products_backend.png

and here is the frontend http://ecommerceoutsourcing.co/projects/UMD/magento/skin/frontend/default/theme542/images/upsell_products_frontend.png

Comment: if you load the product in the frontend directly with the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class and call `isSaleable`, what does it return?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it, how do you do that? Do I have to modify the upsell.phtml? I set all upsells in the backend. Thanks

Comment: @Sander means try opening the product directly. Can the product be added to your cart? Maybe the upsell product itself is `out of stock` or disabled.

Comment: They are all in stock. I made sure that they are all in stock, take a look of the PRODUCT B info http://ecommerceoutsourcing.co/projects/UMD/magento/skin/frontend/default/theme542/images/productb.png

Comment: and all products are enabled

Comment: @KenAvila, Did you got any answer? Please update your answer.

Comment: I already got the answer thanks for your help :)

Comment: @KenAvila please post your answer and accept it as the correct one. I'm curious as to what the problem was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check on Visible and make sure it go with "Catalog,Search" :) That worked for me, hope it help some one.
[image]
Thanks